# Why does training error increase in learning curves?

Tags: machine-learning, overfitting, model-evaluation

I can't seem to think of a reason why training error increases in learning curves as the number of samples increases. Would someone please explain?

[image]

Comment: Because it is harder for the model (with a fixed complexity) to overfit to a bigger training set.

Comment: @ŁukaszGrad I've copied your comment as an answer because it seems to answer the question. If you'd prefer to write your own answer, I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is harder for the model (with a fixed complexity) to overfit to a bigger training set.

---

> I've copied @ŁukaszGrad's comment as an answer because the comment is, more or less, an answer to this question. We have a dramatic gap between answers and questions. At least part of the problem is that some questions are answered in comments: if comments which answered the question were answers instead, we would have fewer unanswered questions.
>
> - [Are we seeing a dramatic drop in answers per question?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2242/are-we-seeing-a-dramatic-drop-in-answers-per-question/5320#5320)
> - [Comments that are actually answers](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/832/comments-that-are-actually-answers)
> - [We have a very large & widening gap between questions and answers. How do we fix it?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5325/we-have-a-very-large-widening-gap-between-questions-and-answers-how-do-we-fix)